# VBA: Determine 'Current folder' in Word after creating new document from SharePoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word, directory

When we create a blank Word (version 2010 - 2016, does not seem relevant) document from SharePoint, and select File > Save As, we see the url of the SharePoint folder as the 'Current Folder'.
Is there a way to determine this folder, without actually saving the file?

Tried everything we could think of in the object model, searched the object browser, tried several google searches, but no success so far.

Even tried the WordBasic compatibility object

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    MsgBox WordBasic.filenameinfo$(.Name, 5)
End With
```

but this shows the default documents folder.

Comment: activedocument.path doesn't do it?

Comment: No :-( ActiveDocument.Path only returns a string after the document is saved.

Comment: oooh that's what was meant by 'without actually saving the file' as in the document gets created and lives in temp space... if you have the option save it in a temp location locally and kill the tempfile; you might be able to use that as a workaround,  but from what I can tell it has no path until it's saved maybe further reading: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211632/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files

Comment: Saving the document in a temp location would set the folder to that temp location. So, the only option would be to save in SharePoint, and that's what we want to prevent. Word obviously 'knows' the location, because it shows as the 'Current Folder' when you File > Save As. We would like to know if there is a way to determine it in VBA. It doesn't seem to be a document property, but we had no luck searching the Application object's properties.

Comment: Is this created from a template? If yes, try ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for responding. Unfortunately, this points to a central location for the template, not to the folder where the document was created from :-(